# How to get the index of an element containing specific child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of `div` elements, some of which contains `h2` element as children (direct or indirect (descendant)). I look for a javascript or jquery to give me the index of such a `div` element. Moreover I want to start the search from a specific `div` element. I mean a `div` element with an index greater than `x` containing `h2`. The following code find the ones in the series of all `divs` containing `h2`. However, some of `divs` may not contain `h2` and should be counted.

```
$(".myDivs h2:gt(2)").eq(0)
```

Html example:

```
<div class='myDivs'></div>
<div class='myDivs'><h2>Hi</h2></div>
<div class='myDivs'></div>
<div class='myDivs'><div><h2>How are you</h2></div></div>
<div class='myDivs'></div>
```

if `x=2` I want the index of 3 for the fourth `div` with class `myDivs` containing an `h2`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found so far, which works:

```
$(".myDivs:gt("+x+"):has(h2)").eq(0).index()
```

Since `gt` is deprecated, the better solution is:

```
$(".myDivs").slice(x).has("h2").first().index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I think you want a jquery something like this:

```
$(start).find("div").find("h2").parent("div").index();
```

From the start element, find your divs, then find the h2 tags in the divs, then get the parent divs of the h2s, and then get the index.

You may need a .each (...) after .find("h2");

Comment: `find("div").find("h2").parent("div")` can be just `$("div:has(h2)")`. [:has](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)